# C# Windows 10 DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm"); не ставит точек

Tags: c#, windows-10, datetime

В программе работающей под Windows 10 нажав на кнопку в которой прописано:

```
txt_data.Text= DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm");
```

Не ставит точки по заданному формату. На Windows 7, всё отлично работает.

Comment: В меня ставит на вин10

Comment: Дело было, в том что там MaskedTextBox и походу в Вин10 там по маске не проходят. А просто в TextBox всё ставит.

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос, указав в нем главное: отображение происходит в `MaskedTextBox`. При этом приведите используемую маску.